# is there an event for holding a button

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

So of course there are events for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` for button presses.  But what I'm wondering is if you can tell when a button is held for a certain period of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any `UIControlEvent`s that correspond to a long press but there is the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` class that can be applied to any view object which will call back to a method via target/action when a long press is recognized.

[UILongPressGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a timer when your button receives a touch down event. If the button receives a touch up event, invalidate the timer. If instead the timer fires, then the button has been held for your designated period and you can take whatever action you like in the firing method.

This is what I've done on OS X, where the situation is somewhat different. Letting the UIKit handle this via `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, as suggested by Mark Adams, is probably the better idea.

Comment: i ended up doing this for buttons i needed this functionality for.  however the post was originally for cells in a table (i didnt say that as i figured its a view thing and not specific to buttons).  anyways, thank you for this, one up